# Left Join tables in Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, left-join

I have looked for the answers to this one but am still having issues and was wondering what I am doing wrong....

I have my MVC project and am using LINQ to get data from two tables in my database. I need to left join the second table however I am getting an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The problem is in my Model and in particular the table that is being joined. Here is my code:

```
public void DATA(string searchString)
        {
            newList = new List<ResultsList>();

            var res = from f in searchDB.CUSTOMERS

                      join cd in searchDB.CUSTOMER_DETAILS
                        on f.cust_id equals cd.cust_id into grouped
                        from gr in grouped.DefaultIfEmpty()

                      where f.ProductName.Equals(searchString)
                      select new { f, gr };


        foreach (var item in surname)
        {
            ResultsList rl = new ResultsList();

            rl.Forename = item.f.Forename;
            rl.Postcode = item.gr.postcode;
            rl.ProductName = item.f.ProductName;

            newList.Add(rl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Fix your code. Where the definition of *surname*?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

sorry, it should be "res" but that wasnt the issue. I have resolved this anyway. If anyone is interested, this is how I done it.

in the foreach part, I added an if statement to see whether the column in the joined table was null and then applied everything I needed minus the joined column else I used everything required from both tables.

```
foreach (var item in res)
        {
            ResultsList rl = new ResultsList();

            if (item.gr != null)
            {
                rl.Forename = item.f.Forename;
                rl.Postcode = item.gr.postcode;
                rl.ProductName = item.f.ProductName;
            }
            else
            {
                rl.Forename = item.f.Forename;
                rl.ProductName = item.f.ProductName;

            }
```

Comment: Your question asked linq to entities and left join, yet you ignored the proposed solutions, and accepted your own answer that did not in fact directly answer your question (even though it may have solved your problem)

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your code and get rid of the for loop by writing:

```
var rl = (from f in searchDB.CUSTOMERS
          join cd in searchDB.CUSTOMER_DETAILS
            on f.cust_id equals cd.cust_id into grouped
          from gr in grouped.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where f.ProductName == searchString
          select new ResultsList
          {
              Forename = f.Forename,
              Postcode = gr == null ? null : gr.postcode,
              ProductName = f.ProductName
          }).ToList();
```

It might work with just `Postcode = gr.postcode` also. Depending on how smart the Linq database provider is.